# Jmeter http request connection timeout after 180 concurrent users are passed

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing, load-testing, connection-timeout

We are getting connection timeout for http request after 180 concurrent users are passed? How to handle concurrent users? We are using single login credentials for all 500 users ? Will that effect the flow

Answer (score 0):

> We are getting connection timeout for http request after 180 concurrent users are passed? How to handle concurrent users?

What is `Thread Group` settings Ramp-Up period and do you have Timers in your test?
You can play with different [Thread Group types](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/) to simulate the actual user behavior as best as possible, because it is a very important. I suppose for now you have all users come in the same moment, so that's why you get connection timeout. So, try to do this:

1. Setup Ramp-Up period, suitable for you situation.

   > For instance, if you configure Thread Group to have 100 threads, and set Ramp-up Period to 0 (or to a small number), then all the threads would start at the same time, and it would produce an unwanted spike of the load. On top of that, if you set Ramp-up Period too high, it might result in "too few" threads being available at the very beginning to achieve the required load.
2. Add [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to simulate User behavior.
3. Try another [Thread Group types](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/)

> We are using single login credentials for all 500 users ? Will that effect the flow

Actually, it depends on the application under testing. Better to ask your developer how it deal with multiple user authentication.

But to simulate the actual use of the system is better to use different users. Youu may store and read login and password for them from csv file with [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)